# about $\int \cos^q(x)\sin^p(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

for all $n$ and $m$ from $\mathbb{N}$ we define $H_{m,n}$ by :

$$H_{m,n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\cos ^{m}(x)\sin^{n} (x)dx$$

1. find relation between $H_{m,n}$ and $H_{m,n-2}$
2. find relation between $H_{m,n}$ and $H_{m-2,n}$
3. Calculate $H_{m,n}$

Thanks

Comment: For the first two, try integration by part twice.

Answer (score 4):

If you let me, I add just some points about the third one. I hope you be inspired to defeat the problem by yourself. We know that $$B(m,n)=\int_0^1x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx~~~~~~~\text{Beta Function}$$ By a proper substitution $x=\sin^2t$, we get $$B(m,n)=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin^2 t)^{m-1}(\cos^2 t)^{n-1}\times 2\sin t\cos tdt=2\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin t)^{2m-1}(\cos t)^{2n-1}dt$$

Comment: Nicely done $+ 1\quad \ddot\smile \quad$

Answer (score 0):

we have $b\left ( m,n \right )=\frac{m!\times n!}{(n+m+1)!} $ and  $ \forall (m,n) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}$

With $B(m,n)=\int_{0}^{1}t^m(1-t)^ndt$ and by a proper substitution $x=sin^2(t)$ we get :

$B(m,n)=2\int_{0}^{1}sin(x)^{2m+1}cos(x)^{2n+1}dx$

we put : $\alpha=2m+1$ and $\beta=2n+1$ so we get  $B(m,n)=b\left ( m,n \right )=\frac{(\frac{\alpha-1}{2})!\times (\frac{\beta-1}{2})!}2{(\frac{\alpha + \beta -2}{2}+1)!}$
I notice that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are odd numbers ($\alpha=2k+1$ and $\beta=2k+1$ )