# Reduction formula

Tags: calculus

> $I_{m,n}=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^m \theta \cos^n \theta d \theta$. Prove that $I_{m,n}=I_{n,m}$, and that $I_{m,n}=\frac{m-1}{m+n}I_{m-2,n}$, for $m>1$.

I understand there is a property with sin and cos that proves the first part, and I have to take out sin^2 for the second part.

Comment: I think this was asked before. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/323984/8581

Comment: @Babak: The $I_{m,n}=I_{n,m}$ part isn't in that other question.

Answer (score 1):

$$I_{m,n}=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\sin^m t\cos^n t\,dt=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)\sin^n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)t\,dt=$$

(and making the substitution $\,u:=\pi/2-t\Longrightarrow -du=dt$ ,we get)

$$=\int\limits_{\pi/2}^0\cos^mu\sin^nu(-du)=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nu\cos^mu\,du=I_{n,m}$$

Comment: Integrating by parts twice for the second part seems difficult.